# altbeacon BluetoothMedic crashes with Android version 12 + 13

Tags: android, bluetooth, altbeacon

The problems started when I updated Android to target SDK 31.

First, I had error in manifest because there was a receiver in a library that did not have android:exported set.  This turned out to be the org.altbeacon.android-beacon-library.  Fixed by updating to latest non-beta version, 2.19.4

Next, I had to add in the new permissions for Bluetooth to my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
```

And also adjust the old permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
```

and also added the feature settings.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
        android:required="false"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="false"/>
```

In the app I'm asking the user for permissions. (this is the one used if the android release version is 12 or greater).

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log("requesting permissions.");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                        {Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
                                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
                                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE,
                        }, 22);
                }
```

Note that I have quite a few of those Crashlytics logs debug messages throughout the program.

So, on *some* devices I am getting various crashes in the altbeacon library.  Example:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE permission for android.content.AttributionSource@881430fb: GattService startAdvertisingSet
       at com.android.bluetooth.Utils.checkPermissionForDataDelivery(Utils.java:482)
       at com.android.bluetooth.Utils.checkAdvertisePermissionForDataDelivery(Utils.java:570)
       at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService.startAdvertisingSet(GattService.java:3252)
       at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService$BluetoothGattBinder.startAdvertisingSet(GattService.java:1392)
       at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService$BluetoothGattBinder.startAdvertisingSet(GattService.java:1376)
       at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGatt.java:362)
       at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1285)
       at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1244)
```

Also getting BLUETOOTH_SCAN permissions crashes of the same general type.

1: All of the crashes are happening within 1 to 5 seconds of opening the app.

2: I am not getting any logs in Crashlytics, despite setting the log messages.  I am wondering if the log function works if the crash occurs in a library?

3: The Crashlytics console shows that 99% of these crashes are happening on Samsung devices.

4:  I can run this on a test phone with Android 12, that is *not* a Samsung, and it works fine.  If I go into permissions settings for the app and turn off "nearby devices" the next time it runs it will  ask me for permissions again and if I deny them it will run without the Bluetooth functions.

Answer (score 2):

For apps targeting SDK 31+ and running on Android 12+, the new `Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE` permission must be grated by the user or any attempt to start Bluetooth Advertising (including by BluetoothMedic in the AndroidBeaconLibrary) will cause a fatal app exception, `java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE permission`.

You can prevent this from happening one of two ways:

1. Before enabling the `BluetoothMedic` to do a transmitter test like shown below, ensure the user has granted this permission.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE) == 
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
  BluetoothMedic.getInstance().enablePeriodicTests(this, BluetoothMedic.TRANSMIT_TEST)`
}
else {
  BluetoothMedic.getInstance().enablePeriodicTests(this, BluetoothMedic.NO_TEST)
}
```

2. You can also use `BluetoothMedic` without the transmitter test -- generally the scan test is the one that is most important.  You can configure this as shown below. But even in this case, you should make sure the user has granted the `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` permission as well as `BACKGROUND_LOCATION` if you want the Medic to be able to do its job properly. If these permissions are not granted, you probably don't want to start it because the scan will just fail.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BACKGROuND_LOCATION) == 
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && 
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) == 
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
  BluetoothMedic.getInstance().enablePeriodicTests(this, BluetoothMedic.SCAN_TEST)`
}
else {
  BluetoothMedic.getInstance().enablePeriodicTests(this, BluetoothMedic.NO_TEST)
}
```

Of course, the above checks only apply to apps targeting Android 12 and running on Android 12, because the permissions were added.   If you allow running on older Android versions, you don't want to check for the BLUETOOTH_SCAN and BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE permissions if running on an earlier Android version.   Sadly, Android permission checks across multiple OS versions have become increasingly complex and requires a lot of code to get things right.

Finally, note that the code above shows disabling the BluetoothMedic if permission is not granted.  This is important because the user may grant permission and later revoke it, which could cause a crash.  To stop this crash from happening, put the above code (including the else statement that disables BluetoothMedic if no permission is granted) somewhere in the `Application.onCreate` call chain, as this method is called before any Android scheduled job (including the BluetoothMedic) runs.  Doing so will prevent a background crash if BluetoothMedic has been enabled but the required permission is not granted.

For the specific case described by the OP, I suspect this is a race condition. The BluetoothMedic settings are persistent, so if you turn it on, it stays on. It relies on the Android JobScheduler, which will try and run it every ~15 minutes. And it will launch your app if not already running, so if it does so and the permission is denied it will crash. For this reason, you should explicitly disable the BluetoothMedic if the permission is denied.  I recommend moving your code that enables/disables BluetoothMedic to the Application.onCreate call chain to stop it before a crash.

Comment: Hi David.  In my OP, I have shown that I am asking for the permission for ADVERTISE (You have to scroll the code window over to see it).  From the lack of logs, it appears that my app isn't even getting to the point of asking for the devices that are crashing.  Also, the fact that the app runs fine on a different phone and gets all of the permissions to run successfully, shows that the code does work in those situations.  It really seems to be something specifically to do with Samsung type phones.

Comment: I suspect what you describe is a race condition.  The BluetoothMedic settings are persistent, so if you turn it on, it stays on.  It relies on the Android JobScheduler, which will try and run it every ~15 minutes.  And it will launch your app if not already running, so if it does so and the permission is denied it will crash.  For this reason, you should probably explicitly disable the BluetoothMedic if the permission is denied -- I updated my answer to show this.  I recommend moving your code that enables/disables BluetoothMedic to the Application.onCreate call chain to stop it before a crash

Comment: Remember, just asking for a permission doesn't mean a user will grant it.  If the code runs and the user doesn't grant the permission the crash will happen.  You must explicitly disable BluetoothMedic if required permissions are not granted, and not enable it until those permissions are granted.

Comment: Hi.  I do have a permissions check set up before I run the BTM, but probably all of these users are ones that had the app running previously before the SDK change and subsequent new permissions.  If I am understanding you correctly, you are saying that BTM keeps running even if my app is shut down, and the next time the app starts up BTM will automatically run a scan at that point before my app even gets through its startup.  Because these users have never gotten to the point of allowing permissions, it dies almost immediately.  I will check this out and let you know.

Comment: I think that is exactly right.  This is understandably a tricky case.

Comment: Hi David.  It looks like this was absolutely what was happening.  I put code in the onCreate event of MyApplication.java to stop the BTM from scanning (which, by the way is totally non-intuitive as you have to use the "enablePeriodicTests" function to do this).  Now it appears that the app is running fine as I have had several hundred updates done and no crashes in the new version over a few days now.  If you could submit your comment as an answer I'll select it as such.

Comment: Glad to hear that is the issue!  I updated my answer to include the comments above.    I am also looking to augment the Android Beacon Library to explicitly check for these permissions as needed before running tests to prevent these crashes from happening.

Comment: Thanks David.  I did see in the manifest for the altbeacon library that it only has the old BLUETOOTH and BLUTOOTH_ADMIN permissions and not the new ones for Android 12, even though it shows target SDK as 31.

Comment: @RobertT I made a code change to automatically prevent crashes in the library for this case.  Do you have the ability to test this in your app if I provide a beta library build?  https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/pull/1121